# How can I test whether this Javascript object has any properties?

Tags: javascript

I have some code that adds properties to an object like this:

```
var MyObject = new Object();

if (....) { MyObject.prop1 = .... ; }
if (....) { MyObject.prop2 = .... ; }
if (....) { MyObject.prop3 = .... ; }
```

After going through all these if statements, I want to test and see whether `MyObject` has properties. I don't want to test if it has `prop1 || prop2 || prop3` because there are 12 properties that can be added.

How do I test to see if it has at least one? I tried `if (MyObject)` but of course that doesn't work because that only tests the existence of the object. Is these something like a simple one-liner like `(MyArray.length)` for objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if object has any properties in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673121/how-to-check-if-object-has-any-properties-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working in a pre-ECMAScript5 environment, it's easy enough with a small loop:

```
var found = false, name;
for (name in MyObject) {
    if (MyObject.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or since you're using `var MyObject = new Object();` to create it (BTW, you can just use `var MyObject = {};`), you don't actually need the `hasOwnProperty` call:

```
var found = false, name;
for (name in MyObject) {
    found = true;
    break;
}
```

[`for..in`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4) loops through the enumerable properties of an object, both its own and ones it inherits from its prototype; [`hasOwnProperty`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.5) tells you whether the property comes from the object itself or its prototype. All of the properties you're adding will be enumerable, so they'll show up in the loop. Raw objects (`{}`) have no enumerable properties initially unless someone has been mucking about with `Object.prototype` (which is a *Really Bad Idea*), hence the second loop above.

ECMAScript5 (released a couple of years ago, not supported by older browsers and support varies a bit even in more recent ones) adds a couple of functions you could use for this. Probably the most relevant is [`Object.keys`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.14), which returns an array of the names of the object's "own" properties (not properties it inherits from its prototype). That would mean you wouldn't need the loop:

```
if (Object.keys(MyObject).length) { // Only on ES5-compliant browsers
    // Yes it has at least one
}
```

Comment: ok, this looks safer for cross-browser compatibility. Can I write for (var name in MyObject) {.... ?

Comment: @frenchie: Yes, you can, it's totally fine syntactically. It's misleading, though: *[Poor, misunderstood `var`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)*

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyObject).length;
```

This will give you number of object's own properties.

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).

> Object.getOwnPropertyNames returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable and non-enumerable properties found directly upon obj.

If you want to support older browsers that don't have `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` use this:

```
var getPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames || function(obj) {
  var propNames = [];
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
      propNames.push(propName);
    }
  }
  return propNames;
}  

getPropertyNames(MyObject).length; // number of own properties
```

Comment: This is not supported by IE versions less than 9.

Comment: It's not very safe code; it could fail in more than one browser. But it's cool.

Comment: frenchie depends on how cross browser compliant you would like to be.

Comment: @frenchie I updated my answer to include a fallback implementation if `getOwnPropertyNames` is not defined. In case you need to support older browsers (which is a good idea) :).