# Cascading undefined testing

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to synthetize a "nil or empty" testing like this one ?

```
if (!shoppingCartLine ||
    !shoppingCartLine.relationships ||
    !shoppingCartLine.relationships.offer ||
    !shoppingCartLine.relationships.offer.links ||
    !shoppingCartLine.relationships.offer.links.self)
return null;
```

to an helper like this :

```
if (isNilOrEmpty(shoppingCartLine.relationships.offer.links.self))
return null;
```

or maybe like C#6.0 Null-Conditional Operator :

```
if (!shoppingCartLine?.relationships?.offer?.links?.self)
return null;
```

without throwing an error :

```
Cannot read property 'links' of undefined
```

Comment: Do you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673121/how-to-check-if-object-has-any-properties-in-javascript ?