# typescript check object is not empty with any object definition

Tags: typescript

Here is my current code:

```
interface ObjectIsEmptyProps {
  [index: string]: number | string;
}
export const objectIsEmpty = (a: ObjectIsEmptyProps) => a &&  
Object.keys(a).length >
```

I need to check an object that might have any number properties provided to it. So 3 examples of possible function calls are:

```
objectIsEmpty({}) //true
objectIsEmpty({ jamie: 'hutber' }) //false
objectIsEmpty({fank: 'skinner', jamie: 'hutber' }) //false
objectIsEmpty({anArray: [], aBoolie: false, chickenSkin: 'isGreat'}) //false
```

So my function can take an object with an undetermined set of properties. Currently the only way I can TS to be happy is to use `any` as the type of the argument.

How can I support any number of object properties without using any?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at the question! Could I please get some feedback on how to improve the question after the downvote. Thanks

Comment: How about `!Object.keys(a).length != 0`

Comment: The issue will still exist that I cannot define the types of the function to accept any shaped object.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, however here are some ways https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673121/how-to-check-if-object-has-any-properties-in-javascript

Comment: Have updated with more clear examples of what I need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. However, could you use the `Record` utility?

```js
export const objectIsEmpty = (a: Record<string, unknown>) => {
  return Object.keys(a).length === 0
}
```